# Inkscape shell loop from windows powershell

Tags: powershell, shell, loops, svg, inkscape

I've written a simple script in Windows powershell to loop through some SVG files and make an adjustment to the page area before exporting. This works well but is relatively slow. Therefore I wanted to try using Inkscape's shell mode but I'm completely perplexed as to how to make this work. I've tried the approach used in this page https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html but without luck. Here is my 'working but slow' script to show what I'm trying to do:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\SVG Charts" -filter *.svg

# Starts a FOR loop which runs through each of the files from above
foreach ($f in $files){
     
     # Prepare the name of the outputted file
     # So you don't save over the originals
     $outfile = $f.DirectoryName + "\Adjusted_" + $f.BaseName + ".svg"
     
     # Run inkscape
     # The export-area-drawing command below simply resets the print area of the SVG
     inkscape $f.FullName --export-area-drawing --export-plain-svg $outfile
}
```

Below is my attempt at a shell version. I think I have the loop structured incorrectly and need to put `inkscape --shell` outside of the loop, however then it just hangs, waiting for input. If I put it inside the loop, then I'm prompted to type quit for each iteration and am then presented with lots of red error text which I think is probably related to the next point... There seem to be several different ways of writing shell commands and I don't know if I'm even using the right approach! I'm struggling to address the last point because I don't know if I've even set the loop up in the correct way to use shell.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\SVG Charts" -filter *.svg

# Starts a FOR loop which runs through each of the files from above
foreach ($f in $files){
     
     # Prepare the name of the outputted file
     # So you don't save over the originals
     $outfile = $f.DirectoryName + "\Adjusted_" + $f.BaseName + ".svg"
     
     # The export-area-drawing command below simply resets the print area of the SVG
     inkscape --shell
     file-open:$f.FullName; export-area-drawing; export-filename:$outfile; export-do

}
```

**My question is: How should I structure this Powershell loop and what syntax should I be using to run shell commands?**

I'm running a relatively old version of Inkscape which no doubt doesn't help: Inkscape 0.92.3

Comment: Command line syntax has changed significantly between 0.92.5 and 1.0. So do not refer to the man page you linked to, which is for the current version. Instead, find it in your Inkscape installation or in the Inkscape repository at https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/tree/INKSCAPE_0_92_3/man (or use a newer Inkscape version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Moini suggests, please upgrade your version of Inkscape.  I was only able to make this work with the latest Inkscape version 1.0.1:

```
# Avoid specifying long file paths in Inkscape commands...
Set-Location -Path 'C:\Temp\SVG Charts'

# Build-up a list of actions to send to Inkscape...
[string]$actions = ''
$files = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.svg
foreach ($f in $files) {
    $actions += "file-open:$($f.Name); export-area-drawing; export-filename:Adjusted_$($f.Name); export-do`r`n"
}

# Ensure to end your list of actions with 'quit', then pipe it to Inkscape...
"$actions`r`nquit" | & "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\bin\inkscape.com" --shell
```

I hope this short example is helpful.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll have to negotiate with our IT team to update the version of Inkscape they make available to us